# R: draw from a vector using custom probability function

Tags: r, distribution, sample

Forgive me if this has been asked before (I feel it must have, but could not find precisely what I am looking for).

Have can I draw one element of a vector of whole numbers (from 1 through, say, 10) using a probability function that specifies different chances of the elements. If I want equal propabilities I use `runif()`  to get a number between 1 and 10:

```
ceiling(runif(1,1,10))
```

How do I similarly sample from e.g. the exponential distribution to get a number between 1 and 10 (such that 1 is much more likely than 10), or a logistic probability function (if I want a sigmoid increasing probability from 1 through 10).

The only "solution" I can come up with is first to draw e6 numbers from the say sigmoid distribution and then scale min and max to 1 and 10 - but this looks clumpsy.

**UPDATE:**

This awkward solution (and I dont feel it very "correct") would go like this

```
#Draw enough from a distribution, here exponential
x <- rexp(1e3)

#Scale probs to e.g. 1-10
scaler <- function(vector, min, max){
 (((vector - min(vector)) * (max - min))/(max(vector) - min(vector))) + min  
} 

x_scale <- scaler(x,1,10)

#And sample once (and round it)
round(sample(x_scale,1))
```

Are there not better solutions around ?

Comment: I think you need to look at `sample()`. Your code is equivalent to `sample(1:10, 1)`, and you can specify probabilities with `prob=` parameter

Comment: Yes, but how can you specify a logistic probability there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `sample()` is what you are looking for, as @HubertL mentioned in the comments. You can specify an increasing function (e.g. `logit()`) and pass the vector you want to sample from `v` as an input. You can then use the output of that function as a vector of probabilities `p`. See the code below.

```
logit <- function(x) {
  return(exp(x)/(exp(x)+1))
}

v <- c(seq(1,10,1))
p <- logit(seq(1,10,1))

sample(v, 1, prob = p, replace = TRUE)
```